# How to define function type with optional parameter in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a function with optional parameters that I pass down to another component.

```
update = (flag: boolean = true): void => {
  // ...
}
```

In the component that I pass this down to, I have a field called `updateFunc` that I want to assign this function. What should be the type of this field?

## What I Tried

If I define the field like the following, I cannot call it with a parameter.

```
updateFunc: () => void;
```

If I define the field like the following, I cannot call it without a parameter.

```
updateFunc: (flag: boolean) => void;
```

If I define the field like the following, I lose the type safety.

```
updateFunc: any;
```

Comment: Is it just `updateFunc: (flag?: boolean) => void;`?

Comment: @pzaenger This works in my testing. Should be an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define this:

```
updateFunc: (flag?: boolean) => void;
```

then the default value will be assigned to the `flag` parameter when the referenced function (`update`) will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the question mark.

```
function hello(name?: string): void {
    if (name) {
        console.log(`Hi ${name}!`);
    } else {
        console.log(`I don't know your name :(`);
    }
}

hello('M. Azyoksul'); // Hi M. Azyoksul!
hello(); // I don't know your name :(
```

If you need a default value, you can use assignment

```
function hello(name: string = 'masked man'): void {
    if (name) {
        console.log(`Hi ${name}!`);
    } else {
        console.log(`I don't know your name :(`);
    }
}

hello('M. Azyoksul'); // Hi M. Azyoksul!
hello(); // Hi masked man!
```